# GKE Ingress Rate Limiting

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

We are using gcp ingress gateway for our kubernetes cluster for public access url . Is there is any way or any specific annotation that can we use to restricts no of **rps** to our services.

Comment: You can't with GKE default ingress. But the current answer with nginx ingress works great!

Answer (score 2):

With the help of below annotation you can set the [RPS in Nginx-ingress.](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#rate-limiting)

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-rps
```

As an example below, the rate limit was set to 5 requests per second.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
 annotations:
   kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-rps: "5"
```

Comment: The problem is if I use class as nginx instead of gce then I cannot able to inbuilt annotation of gce like ingress.gcp.kubernetes.io/pre-shared-cert

Comment: You can't with GKE default ingress as mentioned by Guillaume.